# Which cookie name should be set for authentication when sending a WebRequest?

Tags: c#, cookies, webrequest

Google Chrome inspect menu has a Cookie inspector for each page as you know. I want to download a file from an authentication required site using these cookies. But I don't know which is the right cookie for that.

I used `SessionGUID` cookie for CodeProject as example. But not all page contains such named cookie.

**e.g Facebook uses these cookies:**

[image]

**codeproject cookies**

[image]

How do I know which cookie name I must use to sent login cookie to a source?

Comment: Cookies are domain specific so it wont be any of those. The site you are using can name it whatever they want, there is no way for us to know exactly unless you tell us the site and we have a login for it.

Comment: I guess I found the answer. I read the names using `CookieContainer.GetCookies(new  Uri(url))`. The names are `SessionGUID` and `vk` in order. So the required names are these. But I am not sure it works for all.

Comment: @Crowcoder suppose that we know all cookie names belong to a domain after login. So can we know which is the login cookie by looking the properties of  it?

Comment: Maybe, but not necessarily. It depends how authentication is implemented. The cookie could be encrypted. You could look for common patterns like JWT. If you have a bunch of garbage separated by dots you could decode the data and possibly identify it as a [JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io/).